# How can I connect to an SQL SERVER database remotely within a network?

Tags: string, networking, connection, sharing

So there's a C# application I developed that uses databases.

This application will be used to run on more than 1 machine at a time.

All the instances of the application are programmed to communicate with a database, and there is a separate connection string for each one.

My goal is to make one of the machines the host of ONE single database to which all of the other nodes can connect.

I didn't test this during development because I was content with the DB working on one machine with one connection string.

But now, again, I need all of the machines on the network that happen to be running the application to be communicating with the SAME database, and not their own localhost one.

I don't know if I explained that well but I'm hoping for some helpful answers.

Thank you in advance for any help, and I'll be looking forward to responses.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood well you just want to have 
App A1 on machine M1
.
.
.
App An on machine Mn
to remotely connect to db on machine Mx ?
If your connection string is:

```
connetionString = "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx;Initial  Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
```

Just use the same on all applications. Databases can handle multiple connections. If i misunderstood let me know and i ll delete my answer

Comment: Are the x's in that string supposed to represent the IP + Port of the server computer? Surely that won't work, there are forwardings and network settings that need to be changed, aren't there? That is what I need to know.

Comment: When you have a webapp it is the same thing. Multiple client on different hosts are connecting to the same database. And it is how it works.